# Route matching in Japan

Tags: here-api, here-routing

I have geo points in Japan, which I want to route match
Feeding this GeoJSON into https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/rme_basic

```
    {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               142.7533,
               43.84698333
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               142.7518167,
               43.84776667
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               142.7497167,
               43.84836667
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But it returns some warnings

Response:

```
        [
   {
      "category":1004,
      "text":"Ignoring Trace Point 0, since it is more than 300.0m away from any road link",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":0
   },
   {
      "category":1004,
      "text":"Ignoring Trace Point 1, since it is more than 300.0m away from any road link",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":1
   },
   {
      "category":1004,
      "text":"Ignoring Trace Point 2, since it is more than 300.0m away from any road link",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":2
   },
   {
      "category":1006,
      "text":"Tracepoints have been matched out of order",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":0
   },
   {
      "category":1008,
      "text":"Tracepoint #0 (43.84698333 / 142.7533) could not be matched",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":0
   },
   {
      "category":1008,
      "text":"Tracepoint #1 (43.84776667 / 142.7518167) could not be matched, because trace points before couldn't be matched",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":1
   },
   {
      "category":1008,
      "text":"Tracepoint #2 (43.84836667 / 142.7497167) could not be matched, because trace points before couldn't be matched",
      "routeLinkSeqNum":-1,
      "tracePointSeqNum":2
   }
]
```

According to the [doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/topics/china-japan.html), "additional entitlement" is required, but I don't know what is needed.
GPS locations, for example in Europe, are working.

Is Routing matching v8 possible in Japan?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, for Japan data your credentials need to be entitled.
Please [contact](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you) us if you are interested in this map coverage.